# What's the code for two text boxes to be next to each other in HTML 5?

Tags: html

I'm quite new to HTML and I wish to create a web page; but I just couldn't figure out the code for two text boxes to be next to each other.

Comment: Define "parallel text fields" please.

Comment: For example, if I want to create a registration form where I want to present the first and last name fields parallel to each other, then what would be the code?

Comment: A definition can't contain the word that's being defined ;) I guess you mean "next to each other".

Comment: I was just trying to say that, in another way. Thanks for correcting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure what you mean by "parallel text fields"
but if you want two text boxes next to each other then the following:

```
<div>
    Field 1 : <input type="text"/>
    Field 2:<input type="text"/>
</div>
```

if you want the text fields one below the other:

```
<div>
field 1 :<input type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
field 2:<input type="text"/>    
</div>
```

Comment: the text fields are next to each other in the first div

Comment: you welcome,if thats what you looking for then mark it as the answer